# How do you style the grouping rows when you group rows in React-Data-Grid?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

Is it possible to style the grouping row that you can see in the attached screenshot? What I would like to do is provide a React component that is rendered in place of that.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-grouping-xdd1b) is the codesandbox for the attached screenshot.

[image]

The screenshot shows that the class of the `div` that represents that grouping row is `react-grid-row-group`, and the only place this appears in the `React-Data-Grid` codebase is in `RowGroup.tsx`.

```
const RowGroup = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>(function RowGroup(props, ref) {
  function onRowExpandToggle(expand?: boolean) {
    const { onRowExpandToggle } = props.cellMetaData;
    if (onRowExpandToggle) {
      const shouldExpand = expand == null ? !props.isExpanded : expand;
      onRowExpandToggle({ rowIdx: props.idx, shouldExpand, columnGroupName: props.columnGroupName, name: props.name });
    }
  }

  function onRowExpandClick() {
    onRowExpandToggle(!props.isExpanded);
  }

  function onClick() {
    props.eventBus.dispatch(EventTypes.SELECT_CELL, { rowIdx: props.idx, idx: 0 });
  }

  const lastColumn = props.columns[props.columns.length - 1];
  const style = { width: lastColumn!.left + lastColumn!.width };
  const Renderer = props.renderer || DefaultBase;

  return (
    <div className="react-grid-row-group" style={style} onClick={onClick}>
      <Renderer {...props} ref={ref} onRowExpandClick={onRowExpandClick} onRowExpandToggle={onRowExpandToggle} />
    </div>
  );
});

export default RowGroup;
```

So it seems that if that component receives a `renderer` prop, it will use it to render the group row under the `div` with aforementioned class name.

Usages of `RowGroup.tsx` are basically in `Canvas.tsx`, and Canvas instantiates `RowGroup` with the `renderer` prop being `this.props.rowGroupRenderer`. Canvas is rendered in `Viewport.tsx`. Viewport is rendered in `Grid.tsx`, and Grid is rendered in `ReactDataGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/ReactDataGrid#rowgrouprenderer) for React-Data-Grid we see the prop `rowGroupRenderer` described as

```
rowGroupRenderer
Function called whenever keyboard key is pressed down

type: func
```

However as described in the question above, looking at the code, we can see that this prop controls also what the row looks like when you have a group.

**However, one question that remains is why this prop is not available in the TypeScript type definitions for the props of `ReactDataGrid`?**